# Constantly change the text inside a paragraph with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I was looking for a jQuery animation that **changes the text inside a paragraph constantly**. I've found a solution here : [Text changing with animation jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32330233/text-changing-with-animation-jquery). The problem is that I want to have a bootstrap button under the paragraph and the **button is moving up and down** when the opacity is null.

```js
var text = ["text1", "text2", "text3","text4","text5"];
var index = 0;

$("#description").fadeOut("slow");

setInterval(function(){
    $("#description").stop().html(text[index]).fadeIn("slow",function(){
        index++;
        $("#description").delay(400).fadeOut("slow");
        if (index == 5) {
            index = 0;
        };
    });
},1800);
```

```html
<p id="description"></p>
 <p>Hello world</p>
```

You can see the problem on a fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/km19e3jf/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Alexis has mentioned `fadeOut` and `fadeIn` changes the display property of the element from `block` to `hide`, hence `#description` completely loses its height when `fadeOut` is called.

Not that Alexis' answer isn't good enough (it's great!), but just thought I offer another method that doesn't require other updates outside of what you already have in your code:

```js
var text  = [ "text1", "text2", "text3", "text4", "text5" ];
var index = 0;

$("#description").fadeTo( 1, 0 );

setInterval( function(){
    $( "#description" ).stop().html( text[ index ] ).fadeTo( 500, 1, function(){
        index++;
        $( "#description" ).delay( 400 ).fadeTo( 500, 0 );
        if ( index == 5 ) {
            index = 0;
        };
    } );
}, 1800 );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
     <p id="description">text 1</p>
</div>
```

Amend your script to use `fadeTo` instead since it changes the opacity and not the display property of the element:

Working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/km19e3jf/9/).

Comment: Great! Please accept this as the answer if it is the solution you have implemented. Helps the community know what worked best for the OP

Answer (score 1):

You can add a container to set a fixed height around your text.

The `fadeOut` and `fadeIn` change the display of element to `block` and `hide`.

So the elements below move.

```js
var text = ["text1", "text2", "text3","text4","text5"];
var index = 0;

$("#description").fadeOut("slow");

setInterval(function(){
    $("#description").stop().html(text[index]).fadeIn("slow",function(){
     index++;
        $("#description").delay(400).fadeOut("slow");
     if (index == 5) {
         index = 0;
     };
    });
},1800);
```

```css
.container{
  height:25px;
}

#description{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<p id="description"></p>
</div>

<p>Hello world</p>
```

Comment: Shouldn't you avoid a fixed height if at all possible though? what if the end text actually ends up being longer, causing it to fall on multiple lines?

Comment: It's just a solution for keep his Jquery method. If the text is different sizes, it is true that it must adapt the size of the container

Answer (score 0):

the `fadeOut` function puts a display none on the element after the animation, which is causing the jump. rather than using fadeOut you should use `.css` to change the opacity.

`$("#description").delay(400).css({'opacity': 0});`

in your css, add `transition-duration: 400ms;` to `#description` to animate it.